# Why were the twins named Luke and Leia?

Tags: star-wars, names

In G-Canon, it is not revealed that Padme is pregnant with twins until she is in the medical bay ready to give birth. When asked what they should be named, she immediately responds without much thought.

From [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html):

> OBI-WAN: Don't give up, Padme.
>
> PADME winces from the pain. The MEDICAL DROID is holding the BABY.
>
> MEDICAL DROID: It's a boy.
>
> PADME: Luke . . .
>
> PADME can only offer up a faint smile. She struggles to touch the baby on the forehead.
>
> MEDICAL DROID: ... and a girl.
>
> PADME: . . . Leia.

Is there an EU in-universe explanation as to why she chose these names? Were they possible names that she and Anakin had agreed upon or did the names have some sort of significance to her/them?

Comment: Those are the names that Yoda had written on flash cards in the observation room.

Comment: Because that's what they were named in Episode IV

Comment: In the earliest draft he was named "**Lucas** Starkiller".

Comment: @Richard: Given how he killed the *Star Wars* franchise, that name is very apt.

Comment: @Kevin: It's an ontological paradox!

Comment: Does G Lucas have any kids/relatives with those names? Just an idea

Comment: Of the four Gospels, it is originally only in Luke (24:51) that we see 'on-screen' the physical ascension of the Christ to heaven.  Sky-walker?  @Valorum

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TL;DR, there is no information that could give a particular significance to the name of Luke and Leia.

---

I made a word search in [*Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith* novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_%28novel%29), and neither the word "Luke" nor "Leia" appear before their birth. Remember that it's during the events of *Revenge of the Sith* that Anakin learns about Padmé's pregnancy. AFAIK, there is also no EU material that takes place *during* those events.

So, if there is any dialogue about the names of the kids, it's done *off screen*.

But, is there any occurrence of people using the name *Luke* or *Leia* in their lives? I don't think so. If Anakin had chosen a *significant* name for his kids, he would probably have chosen something like Shmi for a girl and Obi-Wan or Palpatine for a boy. It's less clear for Padmé, but a scan of her [Wookieepedia article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padm%C3%A9_Amidala) don't reveal any occurrence of those names that is not referring to her offspring.

The Star Wars Expanded Universe is vast, but I'm not aware of even a mention of those names before the birth of the twins.

Comment: Palpatine is a surname, and I really doubt that Anakin would name his kid after a Sith Lord.

Answer (score 17):

In this case the simplest explanation appears to be the one, and we don't even need to go near the EU.

Throughout the movies both Anakin and Padme constantly refer to "the baby" - so it's clear that despite whatever technical level prenatal care may have been at, *they did not know that they were going to be having twins* (and that's confirmed by Vader not being aware that Luke had a sister in Episode VI - "so, you have a twin sister ... Obi-Wan was wise to hide her from me").  So it's perfectly reasonable to have chosen two names in advance ("if it's a boy we'll call him Luke, if it's a girl Leia"), and end up using both when two babies popped out.

Comment: Production-wise:  Not worth another answer, but perhaps worth incorporating? -  'Luke' [was George Lucas' nickname](http://www.moongadget.com/origins/lucas_myth.html) in school.  'Lucas' = 'Luke S'.  Also, in the initial draft, [he was to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Skywalker#Concept_and_creation) be non-farmboy 'Annikkin Starkiller'.  Leia Organa [was initially](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Leia#Character_development) 'Leia Antilles'

Comment: So, I just suppose she was really lucky she didn't end up with twins of the same gender as each other.

Comment: @Iszi: The second twin was lucky. "It's a boy." "Luke..." "And another boy" "...Leia". (Replacing my previous comment, which made no sense.)

Comment: I have a friend named Leia, He is Tongan, maybe it wouldn't have been a big deal there, like Chris, Pat, Sam...

Comment: @KeithThompson "Hi, my name is Luke Skywalker, and this is my brother Luke Skywalker."

Comment: @user11521 - Hmm - think they need another brother for that to sound right.

Comment: @RDFozz - only if it’s Darryl Skywalker...

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there's no canon information on where she got the names.

However, it's worth noting that Anakin probably hadn't agreed upon those names at any point--by the end of TESB he's aware that Luke's his son, but (in the special edition) the Emperor says he has no doubt that Luke is "the son of Anakin Skywalker", and Vader asks how it's possible. It's a strange line to begin with, but it's even stranger if he didn't put two and two together the moment he first heard of someone with his last name and the first name he came up with, who's roughly as old as the last time he saw Padme alive. Add in the fact that Luke is a known associate of Leia, who is publicly known to be adopted and (under the theory) has the first name he chose, and it gets even less plausible that he'd take so long to figure it out if he had any input on the names.

Even in the (now-Legends) Expanded Universe, when Vader finds out the identity of the pilot who destroyed the Death Star from multiple sources (one of which is in the comic miniseries *Vader's Quest*, from a captured Rebel), it's the "Skywalker" part he's paying most attention to, implying that the "Luke" part isn't particularly meaningful. (Yes, some of these sources came out before the prequels, but *The Rise and Fall of Darth Vader* came out afterward and referenced most of the sources, still without mentioning any significance to "Luke" throughout.)

Personally, I like the idea that they're traditional Naboo names that Padme never got the chance to ask Anakin about, but that's just speculation/fanon.

Comment: The "how is it possible?" line is more a complaint than a question. It's like "dude, you told me she died before giving birth. How is it possible?" Vader/Anakin knew Luke was his sone the minute he heard his full name. Well, that's how I see it anyway.

Answer (score -3):

I think Padme picked Luke because it means light, maybe she thought the baby would ground Anakin in the light. I think she picked Leia because Anakin always thought of Padme as an Angel, and Leia means heavenly child.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support this?

Comment: 'Leia' means 'heavenly child' in Hawaiian, but it's also the Greek spelling (Λεια) of the Hebrew name 'Leah', which means 'weary'. We need a source that verifies Lucas actually was aware of the Hawaiian meaning of the name, and that he knowingly provided a retroactive explanation for Padme's choosing that name because she was called an 'angel'.

Comment: I'm not interested (for the purposes of this question) why Lucas personally chose the names, I'm asking about any in-universe reason. Given that the story takes place a long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away, it's highly improbable that Padme knew anything about Hawaiian, Greek or Hebrew names and their translated meanings.

Comment: Names have derivations, not meanings. Just saying.